How to get a safe and correct sequential number in a MariaDB Galera cluster?
I'm using Galera with in a multiserver MariaDB sluster.
I'm wondering what is a "by the book" method to get the next sequential number (without gaps) from an int column.
In a single server I would do something like this in a locked and isolated transaction:
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(sequential),0)+1 INTO @myvar FROM mytable FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO mytable (sequential, ...) VALUES (@myvar, ....)
COMMIT;

In a multi-server environment it may fail due to optimistic lock of Galera. But I don't know how to get it correctly.

why do you think you need to always avoid gaps?

A subsequent DELETE or ROLLBACK may create a gap.  And there are many other things.  Hence, "gapless" is a futile goal; rethink the design.

Wait guys, I need a subsequent field without gaps, this is a requirement. I'm not speaking of the PK or general Id. There are many scenarios where you need a sequence without gaps, for example by Italian law (but probably in many other countries) the invoices number cannot have gaps.

Never try to pre-fetch the an auto-increment value.
Use NULL as the value or omit the sequential when inserting.
Always just use LAST_INSERT_ID or the protocol value of the same value to get what was inserted.
There is no reliable way to avoid gaps (even without a cluster - deadlocks and rollbacks leave gaps).
As galera is optimistic there is no replication of a select ... for update. If it conflicts, you'll get a deadlock on commit.
wsrep_auto_increment_control=ON, the default, allows a cluster wide insert without conflicts because the auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset variables per Galera node to avoid conflicts.

Thank you @danlack for your reply, but as you said auto_increment is not a safe solution because it may have gaps. Is my scenario not compatible with a cluster?
